# Can a HMACSHA512 512-bit machine key in IIS be 256 characters long?

Tags: iis, .net-4.0, cryptography

Why is it that when I generate a HMACSHA512 machine key in IIS on Server 2012 the validation key output is 128 characters long but when I generate the same key using the Microsoft PowerShell function (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218#AppendixA) I get a key that is 256 characters long?

This article says the 512-bit key should be 128 characters long and the 256-bit key should be 64 characters long:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx

The IIS gui generates keys that are 128 characters for both HMACSHA512 and HMACSHA256. How long should these keys be and is the gui correct or is the PowerShell function correct?

Comment: does that mean HMAC-SHA-512 should have 256 characters? if so why does Microsoft only generate a 128 character key for this in IIS?

Comment: Ah OK - so maybe there is something wrong with the PowerShell function published my Microsoft (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2915218#AppendixA) since it generates HMAC-SHA-512 output that is 256 hexadecimal characters rather than 128? Or is there some aspect of generating a key output that could double the hexadecimal length and still make it legit?

Comment: Ok - I'm still stumped as to why Microsoft would publish a PowerShell function that creates a HMACSHA512 key that is 256 characters rather than what you say is the correct length and also the length that the Microsoft IIS gui uses (128). I'm trying to validate this PowerShell function is not faulty before I deploy the machine keys that I create with it to a bunch of web servers.

Comment: I was reading this question incorrectly, so I'll set things right with this comment. So the Key of HMAC is *supposed* to be the same size as the output size of HMAC, but using a larger key *is* possible. Basically the (alterated) key and input are hashed together, creating the fixed size output. That still doesn't explain why the key is larger than the hash size though, so it doesn't answer the question. The page you refer to is sufficiently unclear to me to solve this issue.

Comment: Many thanks for your response and clarification. Based on what you are saying and some other responses to this question I'm feeling pretty comfortable using this script. But does the function itself shed anymore light for you on the process they are using? It's halfway down the page in the "Appendix A" link.

Comment: Here is the response from Microsoft Support: 

I checked with our security team as well and there is no issue from a security perspective. You can absolutely initialize an HMACSHA512 instance with a 1024-bit key, but it doesn’t provide any additional security over initializing the instance with a 512-bit key. As long as you never pass a key fewer than 512 bits to the HMACSHA512 constructor (similarly 256 bits for HMACSHA256, 384 bits for HMACSHA384), you’ll be ok. Both the IIS GUI and the PowerShell script meet this minimum bar.

Comment: This is the highest unanswered question for the [tag:cryptography] tag. However, you can simply convert that last comment to an answer and accept it after a day or two - with the added benefit that the answer is much more visible and yes, people can vote for it.